# How to begin at a different starting point for a summation in R

Tags: r

So I would like to read in data and do a summation of one of the columns of 18000 points of data. The thing is the summation requires the variable Tc and then to subtract five iterations before. I don't know how to make it start at its summation 5 data points down so it does not give me an error that there is nothing to subtract in the first 4 data points.

Here is what a small portion of the data looks like:

```
 head(data)
               Time   Record   Ux   Uy    Uz    Ts       Tc       Tn       To       Tp  Tq
1 2016-09-07 09:00:00.1 38651948 0.46 1.21 -0.26 19.53 19.31726 20.43197 19.39093 19.54993 NAN
2 2016-09-07 09:00:00.2 38651949 0.53 1.24 -0.24 19.48 19.30391 20.43744 19.37996 19.51704 NAN
3 2016-09-07 09:00:00.3 38651950 0.53 1.24 -0.24 19.48 19.31249 20.43269  19.3752 19.44648 NAN
4 2016-09-07 09:00:00.4 38651951 0.53 1.24 -0.24 19.48 19.30391 20.40221 19.33919 19.41596 NAN
5 2016-09-07 09:00:00.5 38651952 0.53 1.24 -0.24 19.48 19.24906 20.36079 19.31178 19.38068 NAN
6 2016-09-07 09:00:00.6 38651953 0.51 1.28 -0.28 19.44 19.20519 20.32008 19.30629 19.42693 NAN
```

Here is the code:

```
data <- read.csv(('TOA5_10815.raw_data5411_2016_09_07_0900.dat'),
            header = FALSE,
            dec = ",",
            col.names = c("Time", "Record", "Ux", "Uy", "Uz", "Ts", "Tc", "Tn", "To", "Tp", "Tq"),
            skip = 4)

Tc = data$Tc

sum = 0
m = 18000
j = 5

for (k in 1:(m-j)){
    inner = (Tc[[k]]-Tc[[k-j]])
    sum = sum + inner
}
final = 1/(m-j)*sum
```

Comment: add a condition in the loop `if (k <= j) next` and iterate over 1:m ? also you don't need a loop, I think that `1 / (m - j) * sum(Tc[(j + 1):(m - j)] - Tc[1:(m - j * 2)])` will get it

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a try!

Comment: So:

`if (k <= j) next(
  (1 / (m - j) * sum(Tc[(j + 1):(m - j)] - Tc[1:(m - j * 2)]))`

Then I can assign that a new variable to view it or save it to a new array?

Comment: no use the entire vector in `1 / (m - j) * sum(Tc[(j + 1):(m - j)] - Tc[1:(m - j * 2)])` and skip the loop completely

Comment: `data <- read.csv(('TOA5_10815.raw_data5411_2016_09_07_0900.dat'),
                header = FALSE,
                dec = ",",
                col.names = c("Time", "Record", "Ux", "Uy", "Uz", "Ts", "Tc", "Tn", "To", "Tp", "Tq"),
                skip = 4)
Tc = data$Tc
m = 18000
j = 5

summation <- (1 / (m - j) * sum(Tc[(j + 1):(m - j)] - Tc[1:(m - j * 2)]))

summation`

okay, so its telling me that 

Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Tc[(j + 1):(m - j)], Tc[1:(m - j * 2)]) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: `m = 18000; j = 5` `Tc` are all numeric?

Comment: Yeah Tc is above in the question. It has decimals. But that shouldn't change anything right?

Comment: it's only numeric if `is.numeric(data$Tc)` is true

Comment: Yikes it says false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information since it is a factor

Comment: Perfect thanks so much! You have been so helpful.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again, but could you help me understand why you multiplied by 2  here:  `- Tc[1:(m - j * 2)]) `

Comment: because k is 1 to m-j so `inner = (Tc[[k]]-Tc[[k-j]])` becomes `Tc[[m - j]]-Tc[[m - j - j]]` at its max value. basically you have to start the loop j iterations in and then you shift the loop by j (if that makes more sense)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

I would suggest you make a more reproducible example for your next questions here (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

To answer your question you can either to this in a for loop as you have been working on currently or in much more efficient way; using one type of `apply` functions (here: `lapply`). You can read more about these functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

Creating data set:

```
set.seed(1)
Tc<-rnorm(18000)
```

The `lapply` function. Note that we are starting on `6`, since `Tc[5] - Tc[c(5-5)]` would just return `Tc[5]`.

```
sum<-unlist(lapply(6:18000,function(x) Tc[x]-Tc[c(x-5)]))
```

Done!

Verifying the function by typing in console:

```
> head(sum)
[1] -0.1940146  0.3037857  1.5739533 -1.0194995 -0.6348962  2.3322496
> Tc[6]-Tc[1]
[1] -0.1940146
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your understanding. The only thing is I don't understand how to read in my data set and do that. I got what you did which I am assuming created a random dataset of 18000 points, but I don't understand how the lapply knows to call my data set since I don't see how it calls the random one that you created.